# Fixing "gBrowser.addProgressListener was called with a second argument, which is not supported" warning

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I submitted my addon to the firefox amo directory and it got reviewed and passed, but the reviewer sent me this message:

> 2) The following error appears in the Error Console. It's fairly easy to
>   fix.
>
> Error: gBrowser.addProgressListener
>   was called with a second argument,
>   which is not supported. See bug
>   608628. Source File: chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml
>   Line: 1840

The thing is I have nver touched `chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml` and dont even know where to find it... so how do I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are calling `addProgressListener()` somewhere in your code with multiple arguments. It is a single argument function - you can find the documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addProgressListener

The location `chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml` is where the function is defined, and line 1840 is the location in the file where the "don't call this function with more than one argument" error is thrown. You can find the file in a check out of the FF source at (I think) `browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml`, but you probably don't need to examine it in this case.

Comment: Found the line: 
   `gBrowser.addProgressListener(self.quickfilter_urlBarListener,Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT);` What do I change here?

Comment: Just drop out the `Components.inte‌​rfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT` argument. You don't need the notify mask parameter in this case :)

Answer (score 5):

That's just a warning about a common mistake. [nsIWebProgress.addProgressListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgress#addProgressListener%28%29) supports two parameters. However, `<tabbrowser>` and `<browser>` elements don't support this second parameter and ignore it (see [tabbrowser.addProgressListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addProgressListener)). People were often using `aNotifyMask` parameter nevertheless without being aware that it doesn't do anything, so this warning has been added to make sure they notice.

Comment: Found the line: 
   `gBrowser.addProgressListener(self.quickfilter_urlBarListener,Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT);` What do I change here?

Comment: @Ryan: Remove `Components.inte‌​rfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT` parameter, it is ignored.